# RGBa image from intel realsense to matlab

Tags: matlab, rgba, realsense

I'm trying to send a frame from the intel realsense camera to matlab.
dDisplaying the image by imshow(...) or image(...) didn't make the job since the image is an rgba image...
I have sent the image as an object from C# :

```
matlab.Feval("getImage", 1, out result, bitmap_data);
```

Is there a function that can display the frame ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play with the exact Feval implementation, but if you were to impelment it directly in matlab there are two options

1.Simply ignore the alpha channel

```
%this says show all rows, all cols, for channels 1 through 3 or R,G,B
imshow(rgba_im(:,:,1:3));
```

2.Use the [alpha channel](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/image-overlay-using-transparency.html)

```
%this says show all rows, all cols, for channels 1 through 3 or R,G,B
%also saves the handle to the newly drawn image
hndl = imshow(rgba_im(:,:,1:3));

%isolates alpha channel
alpha = rgba_im(:,:,4);

%displays alpha channel
set(hndl , 'AlphaData', alpha);
```

**EDIT**

Now that I know your data isn't in the standard rgba format here is the code to fix it, the comments should tell you everything you need

```erlang
[num_rows,num_cols_x4]=size(rgba_matrix);

%we have to transpose the array to get it to unfold properly, which is
%first by columns, then rows
at = rgba_matrix.';

%converts data from [r1 g1 b1 a1 r2 g2 b2 a2 r3 g3 b3 a3....] to 
% red_chan   = [r1 r2 r3...]
% green_chan = [g1 g2 g3...]
% blue_chan  = [b1 b2 b3...]
% alpha_chan = [a1 a2 a3...] 
% it says start at some index and grab every 4th element till the end of the
% matrix
red_chan = at(1:4:end);
grn_chan = at(2:4:end);
blu_chan = at(3:4:end);
alp_chan = at(4:4:end);

% reshape each channel from one long vector into a num_rows x (num_cols_x4/4)
red_chan = reshape(red_chan, num_cols_x4/4, num_rows).';
grn_chan = reshape(grn_chan, num_cols_x4/4, num_rows).';
blu_chan = reshape(blu_chan, num_cols_x4/4, num_rows).';
alp_chan = reshape(alp_chan, num_cols_x4/4, num_rows).';

% we concatenate the channels into a num_rows x (num_cols_x4/4) x 4 matrix
standard_rgba = cat(3,red_chan,grn_chan,blu_chan,alp_chan);
```

From this point you can do the processing I suggested using the `standard_rgba` array. There may be a more efficient way to write this code, but I wanted to make it as clear and easy to follow as possible, hope this helps

Comment: Hey @andrew,
The object sent to matlab is an array that is constructed in that way : [R,G,B,A,R,G,B,A,R,G,B,A.....], the first bit of the Red matrix, the first bit of the Green matrix, the first bit of the Blue matrix and the first bit of the Alpha matrix... So do I have to go over the array and construct  the matrices or there is a more clever way to do it in matlab ?? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: @MarounSassine I added some code to convert your matrix to a standard rgba format. I assumed that if your image is `MxN` that your rgba matrix was `Mx(N*4)` since every column was expanded to r,g,b,a. hope this helps

Comment: @MarounSassine - did this work for you? And I think you meant "first pixel value of the Red matrix" and not "first bit of the Red matrix"...

Comment: @andrew - an alternate solution would be to use `standard_rgba=shiftdim(reshape(original_RGBA,4,height,width),1)`